# chmod 444 on 800 files in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I have almost 800 files in a directory which is `/storage/`. And there are 800 `.dat` files there which are right now on `-rw-rw-r--` permission. I want to change all those files to read-only mode. I have tried this:

```
find /storage/ -name "*.dat" | xargs chmod 444
```

on local machine and it's working fine for 10 or 20 files. But when I ssh to my server and do the same command for those 800 files, it took 20 minutes and the command is still running.

Is there any specific and fast way to do that? All my files are not on the local machine but on hosted server.

These 800 files are 30Gb each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key difference could be the search time over a much larger `/storage`. May this folder on the server contains a very large amount of any kind of files which increase the duration required to find all `dat` files into this tree. Server-side `/storage` might be slow too.

Next command can give you an idea of this (counts the number of files and folders in `/storage`):

```
find /storage | wc -l
```

---

Also note that the command you run will search for every `*.dat` files as a first step, and then call `chmod` only once with all matching names as a second step.

Calling `chmod` with 20 filename arguments is reasonable but 800 file-path argument becomes to be a bit too much. You system has limitations about the length of command-line argument (see `xargs --show-limits`).

I would suggest you directly ask [`find`](http://xargs%20--show-limits) to execute your command which will break `chmod` calls in several sub-sets. Next command will call `chmod` once per folder containing `dat` files, which appears reasonable:

```
find /storage -type f -name '*.dat' -execdir chmod 444 '{}' \+
```

- To fork one `chmod` per matching file you need to replace `\+` with `\;`
- To have a better idea of the progression you can add argument `--changes` or `--verbose` to `chmod` call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug the problem. Generate a script with

```
echo '#!/bin/sh' > bigscript.sh
find /storage/ -name "*.dat" | xargs -n 1 echo chmod 444 >> bigscript.sh
chmod u+x bigscript.sh
```

Then edit bigscript and put in debugging information (`echo A`, `echo B`, ...) after some lines and look for errors.

The size of the files doesn't matter; 800 files take few time.

**Alternatives**

Simple alternative: try `chmod -v`; this tells you what chmod is doing.

Other alternative: find the PID of the running chmod (-> CHMODPID) and look at `ls -l /proc/$CHMODPID/fd`

Comment: `find /storage/ -name "*.dat" | xargs -n 1 echo chmod 444 >> bigscript.sh` its just running and running and just running.. There could be one reason that there is a read ops is going on all these files? i should stop the read op first?

Comment: 800 files shall take few time. There must be pretty heavy "read ops" going on. This is a poor perfomance. It sounds to me as if the disk is very slow. Or are you using sshfs? I'd suggest not to change permissions via sshfs but log in to a real server's shell with ssh and type the chmod command there.

Comment: What happens if you try `ls -lR /storage/`? Is there a common place where it hangs?

Comment: I only see one thing that i run the command then the cursor is just blinking nothing happening..

Comment: actually there is a systm which is sending read requests and write requests to these files every second..

Comment: One read op per second on _1 file_ or on _800 files_ (*.dat) or on possibly _10000 files_ (*)? How many bytes are read per read

Comment: 800 files a system is sending read requests to it directly..

Comment: 800 reads per second shall be fine if every read is < ~ 1000 Byte. But it will fail if it is > ~ 500000 Byte. (Of course this depends on hardware, network, etc.)

Comment: The key point is: why "its working fine for 10 or 20 files" but not for 800?

Comment: Is this still true: "its working fine for 10 or 20 files"? Which command do you use for that?

Comment: the same command i mentioned in the question

Comment: So `find /storage/ -name "*.dat"` gives 10-20 files and `find /storage/ -name "*.dat"` gives 800 files???? Where come the reads from? Please answer the question above: is there sshfs? Maybe nfs? You must explain what you're doing. You don't give enough information!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49184/discussion-between-u-ltd-and-junaid-farooq).